# How can I convert a List to an Array in FreeMarker?

Tags: freemarker

I have this Array (*SimpleSequence*):

```
<#assign arrayList = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500] />

<#list arrayList as item>
    <#assign addToArray = "<p>" + item + "</p>" />
</#list>
```

I want to add the `addToArray` to a new Array.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What output or other end result do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: I set up preferences for a portlet in Liferay and there is a method that needs an array `portletSetup.setValues("key", array)`. I have the array but before passing it to setValues I want to wrap each item in an HTML tag and then pass the parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the comments you want to transform each item of a sequence to create another sequence (list or array... FreeMarker doesn't care). Unfortunately there's no `map` function in FTL (as of 2.3.25), but as far as the sequence is not very long (as then this becomes slow), you can work that around with sequence concatenation:

```
<#assign array = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500] />

<#assign mappedArray = []>
<#list array as item>
    <#assign mappedArray += ["<p>${item}</p>"]>
</#list>
```

(In case Liferay uses a too old version, you may have to write `<#assign mappedArray = mappedArray + ["<p>${item}</p>"]>` instead.)